# Checkbox's event handler not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm using textboxes to store certain values, but only if a corresponding checkbox is clicked. Otherwise the textboxes are disabled. The textboxes and the checkboxes are dynamically generated. So, I've used the `on` method. The text boxes are `$text`, `$qnty`, `$unit` and `$price`, each followed by the row id. The associated checkbox is called `selected[]` and has a class of `itemCbox`. For that, my jQuery code is:

```
$("#listDB").on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {
    var id = this.value;
    $text = $("#text"+id);
    $qnty = $("#qnty"+id);
    $unit = $("#unit"+id);
    $price = $("#price"+id);

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        $text.css('background-color', '#fff');
        $text.attr('disabled', false);
        $qnty.attr('disabled', false);
        $unit.attr('disabled', false);
        $price.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $text.css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
        $text.attr('disabled', true);
        $qnty.attr('disabled', true);
        $unit.attr('disabled', true);
        $price.attr('disabled', true);
        $text.val('');
        $qnty.val('--');
        $unit.val('--');
        $price.val('0.00');
    }
});
```

On selecting the cancel option in a dialog, I want the checkboxes to automatically be unchecked, and the corresponding textboxes to be disabled. To acheive this, further down, I use the code:

```
$("#cancelInsert").click(function(event){
    $("input:checked[name='selected[]']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);;
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

This kinda works - the checkboxes are unchecked, but the associated textboxes are not disabled. Why is this? The corresponding event handler `$("#listDB").on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {...}` is not firing. Why is this and how do I fix this?

I'm guessing this is because the event is only activated when the conditions for `.on("click", ".itemCbox"` are met, and simply triggering `click` is not enough. Is that correct?

### Edit

I've modified the code to:

```
$("#cancelInsert").click(function(event){
    $("input:checked[name='selected[]']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
        console.log("Test Statement");
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

The output suggests that everything after the line `$(this).attr('checked', false);` isn't executing. This is probably the problem. Any ideas why? I've also got the following code associated with the `cancelInsert` button:

```
$(".closeDialog").click(function (e){
    $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
    if($("#action").val()!='submitSearch'&&$search!==null)
        $search.remove();
    $('#searchForm')[0].reset();
});
$(".cancelButton").click(function (e){
    $("input:checkbox[name='selected[]']").prop('checked', false);
    $(".closeDialog").click();
});

$("#cancelEdit").click(function (e){
    $("input:checkbox[name='selected[]']").prop('checked', false);
    $(".closeDialog").click();
});
```

---

### Code Dump

My entire HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SomuFinance - Add Items to Bill</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/indexStyle.css">
    <script src="../../scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/addToBill.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="list" method="post" action="addToBill.php">
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Add Items</h1>
            <input type="button" class="button" name="back" id="back" value="&larr; Go Back to Bill" />
            <select name="category_selector" id="category_selector">
                <option value="All" selected>All</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" class="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add Selected Items" />
            <input type="button" class="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit and Add" />
            <input type="button" id="showSearch" class="button" name="search" value="Search" />
            <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action">
            <table id="listDB">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Sl. No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Price Based On</th>
                    <th>MRP</th>
                    <th>Seller's Price</th>
                    <th class="rightBorder">Last Updated On</th>
                    <th>Quantity Factor</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <div class="dialogBG">
        <div id="insertMessage" class="dialog">
            <div class="closeDialog"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialogBG">
        <div id="editItemContainer" class="dialog">
            <div class="closeDialog"></div>
            <h1>Edit Item</h1>
            <form id="data" method="post" action="viewData.php">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" required>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="shop">ID : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="id_disp" name="id_disp" required disabled>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="shop">Shop : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="shop" name="shop" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="category">Category : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="category" name="category" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="item">Item : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="item" name="item" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="qnty">Quantity : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="qnty" name="qnty" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="unit">Unit : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="price_based_on">Price based on : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="price_based_on" name="price_based_on" readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="inp" class=".centerAligned">
                        <label for="editPrice">Edit Price and Date : </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="editPrice" value="editPrice" name="editPrice">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="mrp">MRP (₹) : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="mrp" name="mrp" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="sellers_price">Seller's Price (₹) : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="sellers_price" name="sellers_price" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="last_updated_on">Last Updated on : </label>
                        <input type="date" id="last_updated_on" name="last_updated_on" required readonly>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="qf">Quantity Factor : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="qf" name="qf" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="calQnty">Calculated Quantity : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="calQnty" name="calQnty" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="calUnit">Calculated Unit : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="calUnit" name="calUnit" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="calPrice">Calculated Price (₹) : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="calPrice" name="calPrice" required readonly>
                    </div> <br>
                </div>
                <div class="inp">
                    <input id="insertBill" class="dialogButton" type="button" name="insertBill" value="Insert Item to Bill">
                    <input type="button" class="dialogButton cancelButton" name="cancelInsert" id="cancelInsert" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
                <div id="message"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialogBG">
        <div id="searchDialog" class="dialog">
            <div class="closeDialog"></div>
            <form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" method="post" action="addToBill.php">
                <h1>Search Criteria</h1>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="group">Search in : </label>
                    <select id="field" name="field">
                        <option value="id">ID</option>
                        <option value="shop">Shop</option>
                        <option value="item">Item</option>
                        <option value="qnty">Quantity+Unit</option>
                        <option value="price_based_on">Price Based On</option>
                        <option value="MRP">MRP</option>
                        <option value="sellers_price">Seller's Price</option>
                        <option value="last_updated_on">Last Updated On</option>
                    </select>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp" id="criteriaDiv">
                    <label for="criteria">Search For : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="criteria" name="criteria" required>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp" id="unitDiv">
                    <label for="unitCriteria">Unit : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="unitCriteria" name="unitCriteria" required>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp" id="dateDiv">
                    <label for="dateCriteria">Last Updated On : </label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateCriteria" name="dateCriteria" required>
                </div> <br>
                <input type="button" id="search" class="dialogButton" name="search" value="Search" />
                <input type="button" class="dialogButton cancelButton" name="cancelSearch" value="Cancel" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code to generate the dynamically generated checkboxes and textboxes are:

```
$("#category_selector").change(function(event) {
    if($search!==null)
    {
        $search.remove();
        $search = null;
    }
    $("#listDB").css('display', 'none');
    $("#listDB").find(".catHead").remove();
    $("#listDB").find(".data").remove();
    if($(this).val()=="Search")
        if(!$("#searchDialog").is(":visible"))
        {
            $("#showSearch").trigger('click');
            return;
        }

    $("#action").val('getList');
    var data = $("#list :input").serialize();
    $.post($("#list").attr('action'), data, function(json) 
    {
        if(json.listArr.length>0)
        {
            $.each(json.listArr, function() {
                var $tr = $('<tr>', {
                    class   : "catHead",
                });
                var $td = $('<td>', {
                    class   : "catHead",
                    colspan : 14,
                    text    : this.category
                });
                $("#listDB").append($tr.append($td));

                $.each(this.value, function() {
                    var $tr = $('<tr>',{
                        class : "data"
                    });
                    
                    var $td = $('<td>', {
                        html    : '<input type="checkbox" class="itemCbox" id="selected[]" value="'+this.id+'" name="selected[]" /></td>'
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        text    : this.id
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        text    : this.catCount
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class : "leftAligned",
                        text    : this.item
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class   : "qnty",
                        text    : this.qnty
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class   : "unit",
                        text    : this.unit
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class   : "pbo",
                        text    : this.price_based_on
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class   : "rightAligned",
                        text    : "₹"+this.mrp
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class   : "rightAligned",
                        text    : "₹"+this.sellers_price
                    });$tr.append($td);
                    var formattedDate = new Date(this.last_updated_on);
                    var d = formattedDate.getDate();
                    var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
                    m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
                    var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
                    var date = (d<10?"0":"")+d+"-"+(m<10?"0":"")+m+"-"+y;
                    $td = $('<td>', {
                        class   : "rightBorder",
                        text    : date
                    });$tr.append($td);

                    var $qf = $("<input>",{
                        type    : "text",
                        class   : "qfStyle",
                        id      : "text"+this.id,
                        name    : "text"+this.id,
                        disabled: true
                    });$td = $("<td>");$td.append($qf);$tr.append($td);

                    var $qnty = $("<input>",{
                        type    : "text",
                        class   : "textStyle",
                        id      : "qnty"+this.id,
                        name    : "qnty"+this.id,
                        value   : "--",
                        disabled: true,
                        readonly: true
                    });$td = $("<td>");$td.append($qnty);$tr.append($td);

                    var $unit = $("<input>",{
                        type    : "text",
                        class   : "textStyle",
                        id      : "unit"+this.id,
                        name    : "unit"+this.id,
                        value    : "--",
                        disabled: true,
                        readonly: true
                    });$td = $("<td>");$td.append($unit);$tr.append($td);

                    var $price = $("<input>",{
                        type    : "text",
                        class   : "textStyle rightAligned",
                        id      : "price"+this.id,
                        name    : "price"+this.id,
                        value   : "0.00",
                        disabled: true,
                        readonly: true
                    });$td = $("<td>");$td.append($price);$tr.append($td);

                    $("#listDB").append($tr);
                });
            });
        }
    },"json");
    $("#listDB").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Could you please add HTML code so we can also see the markup.

Comment: @aavrug Added a code dump.

Comment: Have you tried change event for your checkbox?

Comment: @aavrug I did. No change. The event is still not firing.

Comment: Are you checking the console? Does it say anything?

Comment: @mauroc8 It says nothing. Even before the line mentioned, the console.log isn't working. I don't get what's happening.

Comment: You should be using prop() and not attr()

Answer (score 2):

Because your checkbox field is creating dynamically so you have to try something like

```
$(document).on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {
  alert("event is firing");
}
```

Comment: I thought I'm already using that in the line `$("#listDB").on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {...}`? Also, I've narrowed down the problem in the edit. Please refer to the edit in the question, and help. Thank you.

Comment: But have you tried using `$(document)` ? I'm intrigued about this. Maybe jQuery does not read the contents that are added after page load maybe (??

Comment: Also what you narrowed down doesn't seems good to me especially the selector. The selector should be like ```$('input[type="checkbox"])```

Comment: Basically ```selected[]``` this format we give when we don't know about the counting of the input field and this created random name and random id mostly in incremental order. This doesn't mean that you will get this id or name. It will be changed in the DOM.

Comment: @mauroc8 As per my experience this is the code ```selected[]``` used in few frameworks which just represent that the field name will be created dynamically and I don't think this can be used as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#listDB").on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {
```

Replace the 'click' event with 'change' event

```
$("#listDB").on("change", ".itemCbox", function(event) {
```

And remove "$(this).trigger('click');" line

```
$("#cancelInsert").click(function(event){
    $("input:checked[name='selected[]']").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried that. Nothing changed. The event is still not firing.

Comment: Use prop instead of attr:    $(this).prop('checked' , false);

Comment: Updated answer as well

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem in the edit. Please refer to the edit in the question, and help. Thank you.

Comment: Also, the line `$(this).attr('checked', false);` is firing and acting accordingly. The lines after it are not. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip. Use the following code to check the event is actually firing or not. and also provide us the html code to see what is wrong.

```
$("#listDB").on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("event is firing");
  console.log("I m firing");
}
```

Comment: Already added the debugging code you've provided. The event isn't firing.

Comment: use 

$("#list").on("click", ".itemCbox", function(event) {
}

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem in the edit. Please refer to the edit in the question, and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

The problem was in the code:

```
$(".cancelButton").click(function (e){
    $("input:checkbox[name='selected[]']").prop('checked', false);
    $(".closeDialog").click();
});
```

The code for the cancelButton class's click was firing before the code for the cancelInsert ID's click event. This meant that before the cancelInsert button had an opportunity to deselect and trigger the click event of the checkboxes, it was already being deselected by the class's click event. So, the selector `$("input:checked[name='selected[]']")` was essentially empty at this point. To make it work, I changed the HTML code to:

```
<input type="button" id="cancelInsert" class="dialogButton" name="cancelInsert" value="Cancel" />
```

Notice the lack of the cancelButton Class. Next, the code for the cancelInsert's click event also needed to be changed to:

```
$("#cancelInsert").click(function(event){
    $("input:checked[name='selected[]']").each(function () {
        $(this).trigger('click');
        $(".closeDialog").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Simply triggering the click event of the checkboxes that are already clicked, deselects them also, while executing the code in the event handler for the checkbox. Finally, the closeDialog class's click event is triggered to close the dialog box. That's all it took.

Thanks everyone for your answers and your time.